# Reserve staticIP after creation for limit time

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, ip, static-ip-address

we have a code that create staticIP in GCP/AWS/Azure, we are using the IaaS Sdk's to create it, when we create it we are allocating it for our resources, now after some time we are deleting the resources that are using this staticIP, and now its "free"

After a sometime we need to attach new resource to **allocate**  **exact same IP's** that we created before.

we afraid that some process will allocate those IP, so  my question is if there is a way to "reserve" those IP for limit time until the "Real" resources will  allocate them again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @al-dann said there is an option in gcp to reserve a [static ip](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) address.

**For existing ip:**

From your Google Cloud Platform dashboard, navigate to `Networking > External IP addresses`.the down arrow under the Type column and select Static for the External IP address that is connected to your instance (recommended method).

**For new ip:**

to reserve a new static IP address for your instance, instead of using the existing one, click the `RESERVE STATIC ADDRESS` button. If you choose this option, make sure the IP address matches the IP address in your website’s DNS records.make sure to attach the static IP address to the correct instance, then click the Reserve button

For Change or assign an external IP address to an existing instance follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign).When you’re re-assigning IP addresses, it can sometimes take a while for the updates to reflect.

For reserving external IP you must have been granted the `orgpolicy.policyAdmin` role on the organization.

If you want to reserve a regional external `IPv6` address you need to give alpha Alpha access to the feature in the gcp project by:

```
gcloud alpha compute addresses create ADDRESS_NAME  \
        --region=REGION \
        --subnet=SUBNET \
        --ip-version=IPV6 \
        --endpoint-type=VM
```

**EDIT-1:**

You can [reserve an ip address and assign to a VM of your choice](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#reservenewip), but charges will be higher for reserved static external IP that is not used.

From this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#ipaddress) you can find

> If you reserve a static external IP address and do not assign it to a
> resource such as a VM instance or a forwarding rule, you are charged
> at a higher rate than for static and ephemeral external IP addresses
> that are in use.

For Static IP addresses (assigned but unused) will be charged with $0.01 for every hour, you can find charges for various types from  the table from the above doc.

Comment: Thanks I know that I can reserve static IP via GCP, but my question is how to keep it that no resource will allocate this IP anyhow and just specific resource will do that ?

Comment: @Jenney check the edited answer, when you reserve an external IP address, that IP is also removed from the dynamic allocation pool so that the reserved address is never used for an automatic allocation. Reserving a static external IP address for a resource ensures that the resource that's assigned the reserve address always uses the same external address.Added the pricing details for your refernece.

Answer (score 1):

In GCP - I think it is possible to reserve a [static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#external-ip) (through a console, glcoud CLI, [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_address) or API), and later use it with one or another resource as needed. There may be [different price](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/pricing#ipaddress) (choose your region in the drop down list), depending on how the address is being used.

Comment: Thanks I know that I can reserve static IP via GCP sdk, but my question is how to keep it that no resource will allocate this IP anyhow and just specific resource will do that ?

Comment: As soon as one reserves a static IP address it can be managed (allocated or disallocated) at any time. When the address is not in use - it is still reserved, so there is a cost associated with the reservation. Which resource is to use the reserved IP address today, and which tomorrow - up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could reserve an external Static IP-[reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#external-ip) and use [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#architecture) to make use of this IP Address.

Basically, for example, you can provision multiple VMs with no external IP, and configure Cloud NAT to route all the external traffic through a single Static IP address.

When all or some of your resources are deleted, the IP is still allocated to you.

You can also specify a range of Internal IPs which correspond to your resources so only those resources utilize this Static IP.

This will also work for Dataflow, Dataproc, GCE etc.

**Advantages:**
Let's say you are using Dataflow to write data into a Postgres server which requires IP whitelisting, now due to autoscaling, determining IPs of each worker is not feasible, also having to Whitelist IP address for each Job run is not feasible too.

Using Cloud NAT + Static IP solves this issue since you'd have to only whitelist a single IP and all the workers of Dataflow would use this IP address for data traffic flow

> Note: In case of port forwarding, you would either need to assign a
> static IP per resource or use Load Balancer

Comment: Thanks I know that I can reserve static IP via SDk, but my question is how to keep it that no resource will allocate this IP anyhow and just specific resource will do that ?

Comment: Allocate your new resources under the same range of internal IP addresses as set for Cloud NAT. And make sure you do not assign any external IP Address to these resources. Now after being provisioned, they will use the Reserved Static IP address via Cloud NAT.

Comment: Also while setting up Cloud NAT, limit the Internal IP ranges, or subnet so minimal resources can utilise them